# cgo **char to slice string

Tags: go, cgo

I have developed a pam module using the cgo.
can not be converted to []string a ** char

`func pam_sm_authenticate(pamh *C.pam_handle_t, flags C.int, argc C.int, argv **C.char) int {
        fmt.Println(C.GoString(*argv[0]))
        return 0
}`

error is

`invalid operation: argv[0] (type **C.char does not support indexing)`

Please let me know if you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cobbled together from the cgo wiki: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices.

```
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func GoStrings(argc C.int, argv **C.char) []string {

    length := int(argc)
    tmpslice := (*[1 << 30]*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(argv))[:length:length]
    gostrings := make([]string, length)
    for i, s := range tmpslice {
        gostrings[i] = C.GoString(s)
    }
    return gostrings
}
```